# prime numbers in an interval

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

I want to prove that π(m+1,2m) <= (2m choose m)

When π(m, n) is the set of prime numbers in the interval [m,n].

I tried induction but it doesn't work.

I'm now trying to think of a way to show directly that when computing

(2m choose m) = 2m*(2m-1)...(m+1) / m*(m-1)*...*2*1

the denominator disappears, and all that is left is:
π(m+1,2m)*(some more numbers)

Can someone please help me? Thank you

Comment: Surely $\pi(m+1,2m)<m$ since there are only $m$ numbers in the interval, and some of them are even.

Comment: OP hasn't made it clear, but I think they mean that π(m+1,2m) should be the product of primes in that interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already know that $2m \choose m$ is an integer, so you don't need to prove that the denominator disappears.  You need to show that none of the primes from $m+1$ to $m$ occur in the denominator, so that they all divide $2m \choose m$.